# Difference between java.text.Normalizer and android.icu.text.Normalizer2

Tags: android, normalization

What is the difference between `java.text.Normalizer` and `android.icu.text.Normalizer2`?

I studied this page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization, but it doesn't contain required information.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizer2 is an abstract class and is not supposed to be extended for general use.

> The Normalizer2 class is not intended for public subclassing.

I did a quick search of AOSP and found mostly internal uses of Normalizer2.